# Swift Subscript for getting columns and/or rows of matrix

Tags: swift

I created a custom Matrix struct but am having problems with subscript definitions. I want to have 2 subscripts, one for getting a row, and one for getting a column. Currently, I have this:

```
subscript(row: Int, column: Int? = nil) -> [Double] {
    get {
        return Array(self.matrix[row*self.column..<(row*self.column)+3])
    }
    set(rowValues) {
        for i in 0..<self.column{
            self.matrix[row*self.column + i] = rowValues[i]
        }
    }
}

subscript(row: Int? = nil, column: Int) -> [Double] {
    get {
        var col = [Double]()
        for columnIndex in 0..<self.row{
            col.append(self.matrix[columnIndex*self.column + column])
        }
        return col
    }
}
```

But if I call matrix[i] it returns the ith row (and if I write matrix[column: i] it says it's extra and doesn't accept) and there is no way to specify its the column if I don't call it like matrix[nil, i]. Which is fine but I was wondering if it could be possible to not have to write anything for the row and directly get the column (like matrix[, i]).